# Multilevel inheritance problems

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

In my app I am using 2-3 levels of inheritances as per requirement, so I wanted to ask is this good idea to use so many levels of inheritance in iOS, where memory is big constraint and whether this will affect performance and what about memory since if I allocate 1 object actually it will allocate 3 objects, including Base?

Comment: Just looking to clarify, you're asking if an class subclasses `A` which subclasses `B` which subclasses `C` if instantiating `A` will allocate separate objects for `B` and `C`?

Comment: Nope It isn't. Only `C (object which you allocate and initialise)` object will be created.

Comment: @Nuzhant zari if a(b(c)) is the inheritance structure means while allocating memory for c, u will only call init method of b and b will call init method for a. I don't know why you need 3 allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a class hierarchy as below where classes to the right are subclasses of those to the left:

```
NSObject->Subclass1->Subclass2
```

If you then instantiate `Subclass2`

```
Subclass2 *instance = [[Subclass2 alloc] init];
```

Only *one* `Subclass2` object will be created. Separate objects for `Subclass1` and `NSObject` are not created. As `Subclass2` inherits all of the ivars from the two superclasses, it will, however, have sufficient RAM allocated to store the ivars from Subclas1 and NSObject.

If you look at the CocoaTouch framework, there are many objects that have several superclasses between them and NSObject.

When considering RAM usage, more important than the number of superclasses a subclass has is the number and size of the ivars and the number of individual objects you create.

Comment: Thanks @BergQuester, I got it. I thought when I intialize child object, parent object will also get initiated.